# DNX Core 5.0 SendPingAsync on OS X

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, ping, dnx

I'm having issues with SendPingAsync in DNX Core 5.0 on OS X. Basically I'm trying to build a small MVC based site that pings a range of IP addresses 10.0.0.1 -> 10.0.0.254. The code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace PingTest1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static async Task<PingReply> sendPing(IPAddress ip)
        {
            var reply = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(ip, 1000);
            return reply;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> ipas = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
                IPAddress ipa = new IPAddress(new byte[] {10, 0, 0, (byte)i});
                Task<PingReply> result = sendPing(ipa);
                ipas.Add("10.0.0." + i, result.Result.Status.ToString());
            }

            ViewData["ipas"] = ipas;

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Fails with the following uncaught exceptions:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply> System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsync(System.Net.IPAddress, Int32)'.
      System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply> System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsync(System.Net.IPAddress, Int32)'.
```

I have uploaded my full source code to GitHub here: https://github.com/00101010b/PingTest1

Being a complete noob at C# and ASP.net 5.0, I have no idea what I'm doing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it'is a bug. Can you file it at http://github.com/dotnet/corefx ?

Comment: Definitely a bug, submitted a bug report. Turns out the OS X version of DNX is downloading libraries compiled for Windows and not Unix.

Comment: Yeah. Now that I see the full stack trace in the issue you filed I can tell that it is it - there was a similar problem with System.Net.Http before....